# Multiple file uploading on Amazon server at the same time in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Hi I am working in Laravel 5 version and i have a module for multiple file uploading on server. I have uploaded all the files on server using loop which I don't want to use. My concern only is that is there any way in laravel to upload bulk upload multiple file at the same time for a single reques?

code that I write is below

```
public static function storePostImages($inputs) {
        ksort($inputs['Images']);
        foreach ($inputs['Images'] as $key => $image) {
            // upload image
            $destination = Config::get('image.post_original_image_url');
            $image_name = Utility::fileUpload($image, $destination);
            list($width, $height) = getimagesize(Config:: get('image.post_original_image_url') . $image_name);
            $file_size = @filesize(Config:: get('image.post_original_image_url') . $image_name);
            $mediumImageSize = PostBussinessLogic::uploadMediumPostImage($image_name, $width);
            PostBussinessLogic::getPostThumbnail($image_name);
            $images_params[$key] = PostBussinessLogic::prepareMediaParams($image_name, 'picture', NULL, $width, $height, $mediumImageSize['mediumWidth'], $mediumImageSize['mediumHeight'], $file_size);
            break;
        }
        return $images_params;
    }
```

Comment: yes, you need to provide more information and some code where exactly your problem is.

Comment: @Christophvh i have updated my question with code that I code

Answer (score 0):

You could use PHP's threading capabilities, to effectively do this concurrently.

I haven't got a code example, as how you handle creating the threads, and therefore the uploads, will be quite specific, and as you have no code, hard to shoot in the dark for.

You can read up more on the official PHP site, and also there are a few threads on here about running Async tasks in PHP.

[PHP: Thread (Example)](http://docs.php.net/Thread)

But this should be what you are needing.

Comment: @jDev i have updated my question with code that I write

Comment: So in essence, if following the example within the PHP docs, you need to be creating a Thread class, that is responsible for doing the upload, the code you have within your for loop would go in the Run() method of the thread, and you would simply call/execute the threads within your for loop. Pretty straightforward with the example provided :)